# JSON to HTML table (with multiple rowspans) in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, json, html-table, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I'm retrieving data from a mySql database formatted as JSON. I know you can load and parse JSON encoded arrays straight in to HTML tables with Bootstrap using `data-fields` and a jQuery function like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: mydata
  });
  console.log(mydata);
});
```

My JSON encoded string comes with objects within the main "object" like this:

```
[{
  1, 
  2, 
  [{}, {}]
},{
  1, 
  2, 
  [{}, {}]
}]
```

I want these objects to be displayed with rowspans like in the following example:
https://jsfiddle.net/GaussianWonder/401bno7p/16/

Can bootstrap parse that thing by itself? If so, how would I go about it?

Currently my solution is to `echo` the whole table after I query the data without sending any JSON formatted string back to JS

In the example from the link I provided the JSON string does not 100% match with the table i'm displaying. That's no problem at the moment, the concept remains the same. A more correct version that matches the table would be

```
[{
  "COL_1": 1,
  "COL_1_DATA": [{
    "COL_2": 1,
    "COL_2_DATA": [{ /* AND SO ON */ } ]
  }]
}]
```

I don't necessarily want to create the table from Javascript. I'm down for any solution other than to `echo` the whole table manually

Comment: If your data is available when your server sends an HTTP response, (as opposed to obtaining it via an AJAX request, in which case the approach would be different) the best approach would be to simply render your data server-side. The reason for this is that you don't want to add any extra time overhead. (browser parses response, then executes javascript, then the DOM gets updated with the correct data) Why are you reluctant to manually "echo" the data?

Comment: @TristanGodfrey possibly because of **laziness**. After requesting the data i need to adjust rowspans correctly so that it displays properly. i need several `SELECT COUNT(*)`s or counting in a foreach loop. col1 can contain any number of col2, col3 and col4 (which are linked with col2) can be infinitely large. I think i`ll end up with a large select statement where i also count everything and manually create the table. I was just wondering if there's any other option to my problem. If not, i might as well try to make a php class to handle this situation from a more general point of view.

Comment: I don't think there's any kind of "quick" fix here, as your data structure is somewhat complex and I doubt that the bootstrap library has some magical way of handling nested data. You'll probably end up having to do this iteration either way, and in that case it's best to do it server-side. But that's just my 2 cents!